# Quaternion(Hurwitz Integers) gcrd algorithm

Tags: algorithm, quaternions

I want a ref or pseudo-algorithm or an actual algorithm for Quaternion GCD, I need this to find out the 4 squares that make up any given integer $n$, I did all the other work but I am stuck on this since there is no information on Wikipedia or Arxiv on how to do such GCD.

Thanks.

I tried to Extend the Complex(Gaussian Integers) gcd but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

The key for these things is the Euclidean algorithm:

```py
def euclidean_rightdiv_hurwitz(B,D):
    #if B is not D, returns q,r such that
    #B = qD + r
    #r==0 or norm(r)< norm(D)
    nor = norm(D)
    for a,b,c,d in [-sqrt(nor), sqrt(nor)+1]:
        r = quaternion(a,b,c,d)
        if r==0 or norm(r)< nor:
           diff = (B-r)
           if hurwitz_is_rightdivisible(diff,D):
               return diff/D, r
```

To implement `hurwitz_is_rightdivisible`, notice that if diff is rightdivisible by D it must be the case that diff*inv(D) is an integer, so just compute it and check each coordinate.